# Accessing a page via HTTPS once forces all future requests to use HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, request, url-rewriting

I am Tani.

We are currently having an issue with a web service for a client wherein certain accesses to our page are resulting in an infinite redirect loop.  We have been unable to reproduce the error, but because the issue is apparently solved by clearing the cache, it seems to be the case that cache data from a previous version of the site (different server, same domain) is resulting in unwanted redirects for some reason we are not quite certain of (again, nobody at our company can reproduce the behavior).

While investigating this, we discovered something odd.  We are currently building a webpage with a series of unsecured landing pages that all transition to a single SSL-secured form.  However, accessing the form via HTTPS (.htaccess always rewrites the request to use HTTPS when moving into a form action) will cause all future requests to the server to be interpreted as HTTPS, even those that are normally unsecured, until the cache is deleted.

By looking at the server's access log, we can see that this the request is being changed to HTTPS before it even hits our .htaccess.  However, because the request is coming to the server with the S appended, we have no way of knowing what is causing the switch to SSL.  It can be consistently reproduced by opening the secured form in one tab and then refreshing the other.  We have tried restarting the servers, clearing the caches (application, firewall, etc.), but nothing seems to effect it.

The question itself is two-fold: first, is it a reasonable conclusion that this SSL-rewriting may, when combined with an old cache, result in an infinite redirect loop?  And second , does anybody have any ideas which might cause HTTP requests to be rewritten as HTTPS?

Thank you for your time.